# Running a large oracle SQL script in a loop

Tags: sql, oracle, sas

I have created a large piece of script which inserts new rows at the very end into my target table.

Script contains many select statements and interim tables.

I want to loop it to run 2000 times consecutively and can't see any alternative than pushing f5 2000 times.

Is there a Oracle SQL equivalent of wrapping the code into SAS macro and looping it 2000 times?

Comment: Oracle has a `FOR` loop just like most programming languages. Check the docs or [here](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/loops/for_loop.php).

Comment: @EdGibbs - Oracle SQL is not a "programming language" in the way you mean it. There is no FOR loop in SQL in general and in Oracle in particular. Rather, Oracle, like other databases, has an closely integrated procedural language, PL/SQL. Your documentation link is to the FOR loop in PL/SQL, not in Oracle SQL.

Comment: What did you search for? I just Googled for "wrap Oracle SQL in SAS script" and from what I can tell, there are solutions offered for people who understand SAS.

Comment: If you go the PL/SQL route you may find your interim tables can be replaced by collections; though their existence is slightly troubling - if you are creating them as part of the script (I'm speculating wildly of course) that would generally be a bad idea, and would force you into using dynamic SQL if you planned to keep doing that. Hopefully you aren't.  A shell or batch script that loops and runs your script via SQL\*Plus might be simpler. Or maybe you can refactor to a single insert that does *all* the work, perhaps with CTEs, but again speculating about what you're doing now.

Comment: PL/SQL can probably help here. However, it sounds rather strange to have a scripts with many selections, temporary tables and insert statements at the end. I don't say that it's never necessary to do so, but it's extremely rare and rather sounds like kind of batch file processing than working with a well-structured database. It may be worth telling us what your script is doing to get some advice on this.

Comment: @mathguy thanks for the correction. You're absolutely right. I know the difference but my comment was sloppy.

Comment: SAS can run sql with `proc sql` and can connect to Oracle but we need more info to help: *Script contains many select statements and interim tables.*...please post an example. *I want to loop it to run 2000 times consecutively*...loop what? Please post your attempt and specific needs.

Comment: You should be able to create a stored procedure that takes parameters similar to a macro and then execute that.

Answer (score 2):

PL/SQL anonymous block is best in this situation:

```
BEGIN
    FOR i IN 1..2000 LOOP
        -- Insert scripts go here
    END LOOP
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you attempt to convert the insert statements into pure SQL?. That is the fastest and the cleanest approach to loading lot of data.

Once you have that set up, then row_source generation can be done by cartesian producting the result set.

Eg: Say initially your table has the following

```
EmpNo, EmpName, Sal
1000 , Mark   , 500
1001 , Jorja  , 100
```

I wish to generate the contents of the table 3 times then i would do the following

```
insert into emp
select (select max(empno) 
          from emp
       )+lvl as empNo
      , empName
      , Sal
  from emp
  join (select level as lvl
          from dual
        connect by level<=3
        )row_source_generation
    on 1=1;
```

This will give the following output

```
EmpNo, EmpName, Sal
1000 , Mark   , 500
1001 , Jorja  , 100
1002 , Mark1  , 500
1003 , Jorja1 , 100
1004 , Mark2  , 500
1005 , Jorja2 , 100
1006 , Mark3  , 500
1007 , Jorja3 , 100
```